# BufferGeometry indices issue

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, buffer-geometry

I'm trying to port some code that I made in openFrameworks into THREE.JS. The code generates a landscape using perlin noise. I made it so that first a static index array is created, and then the positions of the vertices are placed out in a square grid each displaced by a specified distance. This is so that the positions of the vertices within the array can be shifted (up, down, left or right) so that when the camera moves the landscape can be updated and new strip of landscape generated based on the direction of the camera movement.

For each vertex, 6 indices are added to the index array which refer to two adjacent triangles. I didn't want to waste memory storing duplicates of each vertex for each triangle.

For example e.g.

```html
v12  v11  v10
*----*----*
|\   |\   |
| \  | \  |
|  \ |  \ |
|   \|   \|
*----*----*
v02  v01  v00
```

so e.g. at vertex v00, the indices {v00, v10, v11} and {v00, v11, v01} are added, etc.

In my openFrameworks code, this all works perfectly! After a lot of trouble I finally got things working in THREE.js, but have noticed that as soon as I increase the amount of vertices everything starts getting weird - the triangles are connecting (what seems) all over the place, and a large chunk of vertices start to become skipped. At the moment anything up to and including a grid size of 256*256 works fine, but as soon as I increase any higher I start to see all the artefacts.

I'm thinking this is probably an issue with offsetting, but I don't really understand what this means, or how to implement it with my code. I've seen other people use it successfully when they define their indices in order (0, 1, 2, 3, ... ) and instead use 3 individual vertices for each triangle (and add each three vertices for each triangle in sequence). I can't seem to get the same kind of thing to work.

Any ideas? I've got my code below just in case it helps. You can see the parts where I commented out the ofsetting.

var landscape =
{
    size: 0,
    chunkSize: 21845,
    distance: 0,
    geometry: null,
    mesh: null,
    positions: null,
    normals: null,
    colors: null,
    indices: null,

```
generateVertex: function( r, c )
{
    var pos, color;

    // Set position
    pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    pos.x = this.distance * c;
    pos.z = this.distance * r;
    pos.y = -2 + 5*simplex.noise2D( 0.1*pos.x, 0.1*pos.z );

    // Set color
    color = new THREE.Color();
    color.setRGB( Math.random(1), 0, 0 );

    this.vertices.setXYZ( r * this.size + c, pos.x, pos.y, pos.z );
    this.colors.setXYZ( r * this.size + c, color.r, color.g, color.b );
},

generateIndices: function( i, r, c )
{
    this.indices[ i ] = ( r * this.size ) + c;
    this.indices[ i + 1 ] = ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + c;
    this.indices[ i + 2 ] = ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + ( c + 1 );

    this.indices[ i + 3 ] = ( r * this.size ) + c;
    this.indices[ i + 4 ] = ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + ( c + 1 );
    this.indices[ i + 5 ] = ( r * this.size ) + ( c + 1 );

    /*this.indices[ i ] =  ( ( r * this.size ) + c ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize );
    this.indices[ i + 1 ] = ( ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + c ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize );
    this.indices[ i + 2 ] = ( ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + ( c + 1 ) ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize );

    this.indices[ i + 3 ] = ( ( r * this.size ) + c ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize );
    this.indices[ i + 4 ] = ( ( ( r + 1 ) * this.size ) + ( c + 1 ) ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize );
    this.indices[ i + 5 ] = ( ( r * this.size ) + ( c + 1 ) ) % ( 3 * this.chunkSize ); */   
},

generatePoint: function( x, z )
{

},

generate: function( size, distance )
{        
    var sizeSquared, i;
    sizeSquared = size * size;
    i = 0;
    this.size = size;
    this.distance = distance;

    // Create buffer geometry
    this.geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    this.indices = new Uint16Array( 6*(size-1)*(size-1) );

    this.vertices = new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( sizeSquared * 3 ), 3 );
    this.colors = new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( sizeSquared * 3 ), 3 );

    // Generate points
    for( var r = 0; r < size; r = r + 1 )
    {
        for( var c = 0; c < size; c = c + 1 )
        {
            this.generateVertex( r, c );

            if( (r < size - 1) && (c < size - 1) )
            {
                this.generateIndices( i, r, c );
                i = i + 6;
            }
        }
    }

    // Set geometry
    this.geometry.addAttribute( 'index', new THREE.BufferAttribute( this.indices, 1 ) );
    this.geometry.addAttribute( 'position', this.vertices );
    this.geometry.addAttribute( 'color', this.colors );        

    //
    /*this.geometry.offsets = [];

    var triangles = 2 * ( size - 1 ) * ( size - 1 );
    var offsets = triangles / this.chunkSize;

    for( var j = 0; j < offsets; j = j + 1 )
    {
        var offset =
        {
            start: j * this.chunkSize * 3,
            index: j * this.chunkSize * 3,
            count: Math.min( triangles - ( j * this.chunkSize ), this.chunkSize ) * 3
        };

        this.geometry.offsets.push( offset );
    }*/

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors} );
    //var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });

    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, material );
    scene.add( this.mesh );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 which does not support 32 bit index buffers, so as soon as you have more than 256 * 256 vertices, the index buffer can no longer address them all.

From the [OpenGL ES 2.0 Standard](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_cm_spec_2.0.24.pdf) (section 2.8 Vertex Arrays):

> Indexing support with ubyte and ushort indices is supported. Support
>   for uint indices is not required by OpenGL ES 2.0. If an
>   implementation supports uint indices, it will export the OES element
>   index - uint extension.

Assuming that's the issue you can enable 32bit index buffers by getting and checking for the [`OES_element_index_uint` extension](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/OES_element_index_uint/).

```
var uintExt = gl.getExtension("OES_element_index_uint");
if (!uintExt) {
   alert("Sorry, this app needs 32bit indices and your device or browser doesn't appear to support them");
   return;
}
```

According to [webglstats.com](http://webglstats.com/) 93.5% of machines support the extension.

---

You will need to change your `generate` function to create a 32 bit array:

```
this.indices = new Uint16Array( 6*(size-1)*(size-1) );
```

should be:

```
this.indices = new Uint32Array( 6*(size-1)*(size-1) );
```

I had a quick delve inside the [source of three.js's renderer](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js), and it looks like it checks the type of the index array and will pass `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` to `glDrawElements` if you use a `Uint32Array`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Yeah it does seem like something strange happens after 256 * 256 vertices. I tried the bit of code but it doesn't seem to work, unless I have to make some other changes. I'm not sure if there is something wrong somewhere else, but have seen people index offsets to get around this issue. It doesn't seem to work though for my particular setup, I'm not sure why.

Comment: What does your `drawElements` call look like? To use 32 bit indices you'd have to pass something like `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` as the third parameter, but I don't think WebGL has it (I'm not sure though - I don't actually use it).

Comment: @gman Do you know if you can actually use it? according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn302396(v=vs.85).aspx, the type parameter must be `gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT`. I suppose you could bodge it by passing in your own constant. On my platform it's defined as 0x1405 (5125 in decimal). Not sure if it's defined the same everywhere.

Comment: As I mentioned briefly I'm using THREE.JS. I'm not too good with it yet, but there seem to be a lot of abstractions to make things easier. I don't actually have any direct control over how anything is drawn. In fact I don't even have a single draw call! You just add everything to the scene, and call the scene to be rendered.

Comment: @jacknkandy I've updated the answer with some more info that might help.

Comment: Great answer. I think @jacknkandy should accept it.